# Jetty web server is automatically shutting down very frequently on EC2

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, jetty, ubuntu-12.04, jetty-8

Looking for help.
Jetty 8.1.14.v20131031 is running on EC2 Ubuntu 12.04. It shuts down automatically in 3 hours after it is started. Just to confirm that it is not the issue of my code I removed war file from the server and started with default [spdy.war and test.war] but the same outcome. It got shut down after 3 hours. Jetty does not log any error in the log. Just to mention that this issue started a month ago, before that it was working fine.

Here is the log -

### Web server Started-

```
2016-11-28 18:00:30.694:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.14.v20131031 2016-11-28     18:00:30.712:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:Deployment monitor   /opt/jetty/webapps at interval 1 2016-11-28
18:00:30.718:INFO:oejd.DeploymentManager:Deployable added:  /opt/jetty/webapps/test.war 2016-11-28 18:00:30.748:INFO:oejw.WebInfConfiguration:Extract jar:file:/opt/jetty/webapps/test.war!/ to
/mnt/tmp/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-test.war-_test-any-/webapp 2016-11-28 18:00:31.594:INFO:oejs.TransparentProxy:TransparentProxy @ /test/javadoc-proxy to http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-
8/apidocs 2016-11-28 18:00:31.594:INFO:oejd.DeploymentManager:Deployable added: /opt/jetty/webapps/spdy.war 2016-11-28 18:00:31.596:INFO:oejw.WebInfConfiguration:Extract
jar:file:/opt/jetty/webapps/spdy.war!/ to /mnt/tmp/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-spdy.war-_spdy-any-/webapp 2016-11-28 18:00:31.677:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:Deployment monitor /opt/jetty/contexts at
interval 1 2016-11-28 18:00:31.678:INFO:oejd.DeploymentManager:Deployable added: /opt/jetty/contexts/javadoc.xml 2016-11-28 18:00:31.709:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started
SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
```

Just idle. No logging in between

Stopped automatically after 3 hours-

```
2016-11-28 21:11:27.567:INFO:oejs.Server:Graceful shutdown SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080 2016-11-28 21:11:27.567:INFO:oejs.Server:Graceful shutdown o.e.j.w.WebAppContext
{/test,file:/mnt/tmp/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-test.war-_test-any-/webapp/},/opt/jetty/webapps/test.war 2016-11-28 21:11:27.568:INFO:oejs.Server:Graceful shutdown o.e.j.w.WebAppContext
{/spdy,file:/mnt/tmp/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-spdy.war-_spdy-any-/webapp/},/opt/jetty/webapps/spdy.war 2016-11-28 21:11:27.568:INFO:oejs.Server:Graceful shutdown o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler
{/javadoc,file:/opt/jetty/javadoc/} 2016-11-28 21:11:28.589:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:stopped o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler{/javadoc,file:/opt/jetty/javadoc/} 2016-11-28
21:11:28.601:INFO:oejsl.ELContextCleaner:javax.el.BeanELResolver purged 2016-11-28 21:11:28.601:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:stopped o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/spdy,file:/mnt/tmp/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-
spdy.war-_spdy-any-/webapp/},/opt/jetty/webapps/spdy.war 2016-11-28 21:11:28.664:INFO:oejsl.ELContextCleaner:javax.el.BeanELResolver purged 2016-11-28 21:11:28.665:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:stopped
o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/test,file:/mnt/tmp/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-test.war-_test-any-/webapp/},/opt/jetty/webapps/test.war
```

Comment: Posted the problem on serverfault https://serverfault.com/questions/821636/jetty-web-server-is-automatically-shutting-down-on-ec2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started jetty ignoring the hangup signal and this work around seems to be working as of now.  I started jetty with this command [nohup java -jar start.jar &]. But root cause of shut down signal is still away from my sight.

Answer (score 0):

> Note: [Jetty 8 is EOL (End of Life)](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html), consider upgrading.

This question is not really suitable for Stackoverflow, as its not a programming question.

This question would be better suited over at [serverfault's `amazon-web-services` tag](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/amazon-web-services).

`2016-11-28 21:11:27.567:INFO:oejs.Server:Graceful shutdown` means that someone (or some process outside of Jetty) has specifically told it to shut down.

That was not an accident, nor was it Jetty deciding to shut down on its own, look outside of Jetty to find your answer. (service configurations, cron, aws configurations, other users, etc)

Comment: Thanks Joakim. I will post this to serverfault.

Comment: Posted the problem to serverfault also http://serverfault.com/questions/821636/jetty-web-server-is-automatically-shutting-down-on-ec2